# Uploading JPG Images in GUI Java?

Tags: java

So we randomly choose a number between 1 to 6 and whatever is rolled will have an image uploaded of a die face that corresponds to the number. It's compiling, but I get an exception thread I don't understand.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class Butttin {

        private static JLabel label;

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rolling Dice Game");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton buttonRoll = new JButton("Roll!");

        buttonRoll.addActionListener(new buttonRoll()); 

        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2, 5, 5));
        panel.add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
    }

    private static class buttonRoll implements ActionListener {
         private java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            int max = 6;
            int min = 1;
            ImageIcon img;
            int rolledNumber = random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
            String command  = event.getActionCommand();
            if (command == "Roll!") {
                if ("Roll!".equals(command)) {
                    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("die 1.jpg");
                    label = new JLabel(imageIcon);

                } else if (rolledNumber == 2){
                    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("die 2.jpg");
                    label = new JLabel(imageIcon);

                } else if (rolledNumber == 3){
                    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("die 3.jpg");
                    label = new JLabel(imageIcon);

                } else if (rolledNumber == 4){
                    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("die 4.jpg");
                    label = new JLabel(imageIcon);

                } else if (rolledNumber == 5){
                    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("die 5.jpg");
                    label = new JLabel(imageIcon);

                } else if (rolledNumber == 6){
                    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("die 6.jpg");
                    label = new JLabel(imageIcon);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception thread is: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1095)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:415)
at Butttin.main(Butttin.java:20)"

Comment: Put it in the question. Also, your message says Butttin while the code refers to Butin, there is no add() on line 20 and I don't get any errors running it...?

Comment: I'm not sure how the code you've presented relates to the description of your problem, not seeing any dice or "random rolling".  However, accounting for the lack of images, you code works fine for me...

Comment: I'm so sorry, that was the wrong code. This one should be the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not initialize your JLabel before you add it to your JPanel. The easiest thing to do would be to initialize it directly:

```
private static JLabel label = new JLabel();
```

And in your `actionPerformed` method, instead of creating a new `JLabel` every time and replacing the old one, just use its `setIcon` method.

```
label.setIcon(imageIcon);
```

On another note, when working with Swing components (creating components, adding components, etc), it should be run on the Event Dispatch Thread:

```
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //...
    }
});
```